# OCR in Windows phone 8 wp8

Tags: windows-phone, ocr, text-extraction

anyone know OCR Software Development Kit to work offline on windows phone not using cloud.
I tried DevScope but it hasn't a good accuracy

Comment: I think you miss the point of SO...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.